# What are we to deduce from a structure theorem of this type concerning totally geodesic maps?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I apologise in advance for the vague nature of the question, but some insight would be greatly appreciated.

I'm reading a paper of Lei Ni concerning structure theorems for Kähler manifolds. Here is an example of a theorem contained in the paper:

**Theorem:** Let $f : M^m \to N^n$ be a holomorphic map between complete Kähler manifolds with $\text{HBC}(M) \geq 0$ and $\text{HBC}(N) \leq 0$, where $\text{HBC}$ refers to the holomorphic bisectional curvature of the metrics. Let $r(x)$ denote the distance function relative to a fixed point $x \in M$. If $$\lim_{r(x) \to \infty} \frac{\| df \|(x)}{r^{\varepsilon}(x)} =0,$$ for any $\varepsilon >0$, then $f$ is totally geodesic.

Of course, the theorem states that a holomorphic map whose derivative grows slower than any polynomial in the distance function takes geodesics in $M$ to geodesics in $N$. For example, if $\| df \| = O(\log(r(x)))$, then $f$ would be totally geodesic.

---

My question does not concern the specifics of the theorem, but in the more vague question of: what does such a theorem tell me? What do we learn from knowing that under certain on the curvature and growth of the derivative, that a map is totally geodesic? Perhaps I'm missing some results in the area of totally geodesic maps. Any comments or intuitions would be greatly appreciated. Do not hesitate to ask clarifying questions, I admit that the question is terribly vague.